# Jquery smooth image fader

Tags: jquery

Прошу прощения за избитый вопрос, есть "недослайдер".

Так вот когда меняется изображение оно "растворяется" на белый фон, и затем появляется опять с белого фона. Будьте добры намекните как сделать чтобы слайды растворялись сами на себя? Я не могу понять логику на что "фейдить" активное изображение? на бекграунд? или мб с z-index'aми как то играть?

```
var timer = 2000; //time
var count = 3; //images count

var kx = 1;
play=setInterval("autoplay()", timer);
function autoplay (){

$('img').fadeOut(100);
$('img').attr('src', 'http://ul.hol.es/art/slide' + kx + '.jpg');
$('img').fadeIn(100);

kx++;

if (kx == count+1) kx = 1;
}
```

Вот фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/h8ChR/1/

Ну или сам слайдер на: http://ul.hol.es

Comment: для начала, у вас параллельно выполняется fadeIn и fadeOut, делать можно по-разному, по мне проще всего сделать картинку background в div и поставить css3 transition.

Comment: именно так и было реализовано но Ie9 не может в transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно две картинки - одна под другой, как-то так, по дороге исправил несколько недочетов, а именно - setInterval, не нужно кавычки использовать, selectors - лучше один раз выбрать и потом держать переменными.

```
$(function () {
    var timer = 2000,
        count = 3,
        kx = 1,
        play = setInterval(autoplay, timer),
        imgOld = $('.images .old'),
        container = $('.images'),
        imgNew = $('.images .new');
    imgNew.load(display);
    display();

    function autoplay() {
        imgOld.attr('src', imgNew.attr('src'));
        imgNew.attr('src', 'http://ul.hol.es/art/slide' + kx + '.jpg');
        kx++;
        imgNew.css('opacity', 0);
        if (kx == count + 1) kx = 1;
    }

    function display() {
        imgNew.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
        container.width(imgNew.width());
        container.height(imgNew.height());

    }

    //далее лучше переписать, чтобы ловило mouseover/mouseout - см http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/h8ChR/7/
    $('li').mousemove(function () {
        clearInterval(play);
        a = $(this).index() + 1;

        imgNew.attr('src', 'http://ul.hol.es/art/slide' + a + '.jpg');
        play = setInterval(autoplay, timer);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/h8ChR/4/

Comment: Спасибо вам огромнейшее! Просто идеальнейший код!

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), как вариант, можно это дело [оформить в виде плагина](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/h8ChR/10/). При желании, можно добавить динамические опции, настройки и прочее.

Comment: какой-то странный у вас плагин, вот в этой части особенно

          imgs = $('img',wrap).css('position','absolute');
          cntImg = imgs.length;
          controls = $('li',wrap);

Comment: а если все картинки уже  есть в каком-то блоке, то можно вообще  вот так делать: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/h8ChR/12/

    jQuery(function($){
        var slides=$('.slides');
        setInterval(function() {
            var next=slides.children().first();
            next.hide();
            next.appendTo(slides);
            next.fadeIn(300);
        },1000);
    });

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/LTaUZ/ вот с кнопками и прочим.